# How do I set custom locations based on latitude and longitude in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I need to be able to set a location based on latitude and longitude while doing a Headless Chrome (Puppeteer) search:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var url="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
var keyword="hotels&num=100";
var urls;
var desktopUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
const response=[];
var i=0;
var userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";

(async () => 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  urls=url+keyword;
    /*page.setViewport({
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000
    });*/
page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
  response[i]=await page.goto(urls);
  console.log(await browser.version());
})();
```

Comment: There isn't an API available right now. See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1077 for a discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.setGeolocation` api

docs: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetgeolocationoptions

code example:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); // default is true
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // 116.451673,39.923054
  await page.setGeolocation({latitude: 39.923054, longitude: 130.451673});
```

Comment: I tried setGeolocation but does not work. I only see current location. Is this because of chromium browser cache?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [`CDPSession`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) and override the geolocation using the Chrome DevTools Protocol [`Page.setGeolocationOverride`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-setGeolocationOverride):

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

await client.send('Emulation.setGeolocationOverride', {
  accuracy: 100,
  latitude: 24.42312,
  longitude: 105.75868,
});
```